# reactJS binding component's functions to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying access the components state through `this`. In `works()`, `this` is the react component. However, in wontBind's `exist`, `this`, is the window (can anyone clarify why this is?).

Because of this I am trying to bind the react component's `this` to the `exist` function, however I still end up having the window as `this`.

Any ideas how to go about this problem?

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Example',

  wontBind: [{ msg: 'Select a BD',
  check: function exists() {
    return this;
  }.bind(this) }],

  works: function() {
    return this;
  }
})
```

Comment: Because `this` in the `bind(this)` expression belongs to the upper context where that code is running in.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. So it seems I should explicitly pass this in as an argument.

Comment: Note that `wontBind` is an (arbitrary) array and `works` is a "method". `React.createClass` will autobind all methods of the object, but it won't traverse any data structures (such as the array) for functions.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for putting it that way. That makes a lot of sense.